# Differences between Firefox and Iceweasel

Tags: forking, dfsg

[Iceweasel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Corporation_software_rebranded_by_the_Debian_project#IceWeasel) is a fork of Firefox which was made by the Debian project because the license conditions of the Firefox name and logo violate the Debian Free Software Guidelines.

Did Debian do any other changes to Firefox which were not just cosmetic?

Comment: "no" is a bit to short as an answer, so have it as a comment.

Comment: @Martijn You could make it a proper answer when you would add a source or your own research to back up your claim.

Comment: I'm leaning to allowing this question, but I'm not 100% sure. On the one hand it seems to be about a specific instance of open source software, which isn't really a part of our scope. On the other hand, this seems like an addition that could provide a lot of questions. Allowing questions about any open source product seems like a slippery slope though.

Comment: @overactor What is in scope and what isn't is what we are trying to figure out right now. I would propose we discuss this on meta.

Comment: @Philipp [done.](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/q/176/168)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Debian, [Iceweasel is Firefox](https://lwn.net/Articles/676799/) once again, since [March 10, 2016](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-mozilla/iceweasel.git/commit/debian?id=15cc4433d63e2aa8e89339c248634c52d4e95789). There's an [Iceweasel branding](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/iceweasel-branding/) add-on which can be used to restore the Iceweasel branding.

There are some non-cosmetic differences between Mozilla's version and Debian's; you can see all the patches [here](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-mozilla/iceweasel.git/tree/debian/patches). You'll find changes which disable "phone-home" features (Firefox health report), change the way plugins and extensions are handled to work better in the context of a distribution with packaged plugins and extensions... There are also a series of bug fixes backported from work-in-progress upstream versions.

These are the kinds of changes you could find in any package in Debian (the old branding changes weren't, of course, although quite a few Debian packages include minor branding changes — *e.g.* adding a "Debian" mention in version numbers in `gcc` and Wine). The Chromium package for example also disables various "phone-home" features; many packages include backported bug fixes, and changes to integrate the software into the distribution.

Comment: The most visible thing is the movement of Preferences dialog inside menu.